# PyQt crashes on start after (Qt?) update

Tags: python, linux, qt, crash, pyqt5

Recently, after update (which presumably included Qt5) my pyQt5 apps stopped working, crashing on start-up:

```
...
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: symbol _ZN20QMetaPropertyBuilder8setFinalEb, version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

I could not find any hints, nor mentions of this specific error. I suspect that PyQt somehow uses a wrong version of Qt5 but I could find nothing.

Can it be the case that Qt 5.5.1 and 5.6.1 are not compatible for the sake of PyQt5?

Thanks!

Software versions:

```
> cat /etc/SuSE-release 
openSUSE 42.1 (x86_64)
VERSION = 42.1
CODENAME = Malachite
> rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so
libQt5Core-devel-5.6.1-256.1.x86_64
> rpm -q python-qt5
python-qt5-5.5.1-63.2.x86_64
```

Comment: Further investigation shows that symbol _ZN20QMetaPropertyBuilder8setFinalEb is now Qt_5.6.1_PRIVATE_API, not Qt_5. Still have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue by installing the package python3-qt5 built against Qt 5.6 from KDE:/Qt_56 repository.